# add multiple numbers to count jquery

Tags: javascript

this is the dead script for my shooter game (the buttons are just for testing)
but for some reason i cant figure out how to add 10 instead of 1

this is what i have now:

```
(function(){
    const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.counterBtn')
    let count= 0
    
    //Add event listeners and functionailty to each button  
    buttons.forEach(function(button){
      button.addEventListener('click', function(){

        //buttons
        if (button.classList.contains('-1')){
          count--
        } else if (button.classList.contains('+1')){
          count++
        } else if (button.classList.contains('+10')){
          
        }
  
        //Select the counter text
        const counter = document.querySelector('#counter')
        counter.textContent = count
  
        //dead / alive
        if (count <= 0 ){            
            counter.style.color = 'red'
            console.log("dead")
        } else if (count > 0){
            counter.style.color = 'lightgreen'
            console.log("alive")
        } else {
          counter.style.color = '#000000'
        }

        if (count <= 0) {
          alert ("you died")
        } else if (count > 100 ) {
          alert ("u r ful health")
        } else {
          return
        }
      })
    })
  })()
```

can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `+=`, for example:

```
count += 10
```

Of course this also works, but is more verbose:

```
count = count + 10
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Assignment